# How to prevent SQL Compact DB to be erased?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm developing an applciation using SQL Compact database in Visual Studio 2008. When I start the application and run the process, the data is being loaded into database for few hours worth of few tens of megabytes. However, when I quite debugging, change something in code (not in DB structure), run the project again, the database is erased.

Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior? I need the data to stay in DB to test on it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the database file to your project?  Select it and in the Properties window change its Copy property from Always to If Newer.

Comment: I am not sure where to fiind this Properties window. I can't see any Copy property.